# How can inner parts of a mesh be selected?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

This model of a head has inner geometry for oral and orbital cavity in order to texture the face I would like to hide these parts of the mesh before unwrapping.

[image]

How could I select the cavities ?

Comment: What about selecting a vert/edge ring at the back and then growing the selection (Ctrl+Numpad Plus) until it's about right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select an edge ring where the cavity joins with the outer surface:

[image]

Then press *Select Loop Inner-Region* in *3D view > Header > Select*:

[image]

You may need to invert the selection afterwards (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks, this works well. To select multiple inner regions I had to add them to a vertex group and re-select before assign.

Comment: @stacker Glad it worked :) Though wouldn't *select one cavity > hide > select next cavity > hide* etc. work?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for my model (below) where I just pulled some vertices into the sphere head to make the mouth. Did I do something wrong or will this not work if the mouth is made that way?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII It does depend on the topology, you need an edge ring around opening of the cavity. However, stacker's screenshot shows such an edge ring.

Answer (score 7):

### *Select* using *Limit Selection to Visible* and *Hide*

One possible way to achieve this goal is to enable [*Limit Selection to Visible*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting), select the outer surface, [*Invert Selection*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting), then [*Hide*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes) it. This method could be particularly useful if your model has lots of cavities you want to hide.

For example, this mesh has an inner cavity with a pink ball in it:

[image]

To hide the model's outer shell, do this:

1. Select the object, then enter Edit mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>
2. Enable *Limit Selection to Visible* in the 3D Viewport Header so that only faces visible to the camera can be selected:

   [image]
3. Toggle into [Quad View](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>

   [image]
4. Switch to using the [*Circle Select*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting) tool (<kbd>C</kbd>), then increase the size of the selection circle by scrolling up with the scroll wheel (MMB) until you can select most of your model with 1 click
5. Now using the four windows of the Quad View, select all the outside faces, being careful not to select anything in the cavities:

   [image]

   Continue selecting until all outer faces are selected.
   **Note:**

   - Since there is no "Back View", you will have to rotate in the User defined window to select those
   - Once you have used the *Circle Select* tool to select in one window, you must stop using the tool ***while in that window*** before you can begin to use it in another window. To stop using it, click the LMB (Left Mouse Button) in the window you began using it in
6. Rotate the mesh in the User defined window (upper right window) to see if you've successfully selected all the outer mesh. Keep selecting until it's all selected.
   **Note:**

   - Sometimes you have to zoom in and look closely in order for the Circle Selection tool to actually select the geometry
   - If you accidentally select something you ***don't*** want selected, you can deselect it with the MMB (Middel Mouse Button/Scroll Wheel) while still using the Circle Selection tool
7. Once all the outer mesh is selected, *Hide* the selected faces by pressing <kbd>H</kbd>

   [image]
8. If you find you have accidentally hidden parts of the mesh you do not want to hide, then *Unhide* with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, edit your selection, then *Hide* again. Repeat as necessary:

   [image]
9. Once you've made sure all your cavities are properly selected, *Unhide* the outer mesh, then *Invert Selection* with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd>, then *Hide*

   [image]

   Now all the cavities are hidden.