# How do I select circles?

Tags: selection-tools

How do I select a whole circle at once in blender without selecting other objects that are touching it?
I have tried every key on my keyboard and I'm just wrecking the model. I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried Alt + RMB?

Comment: Could you take a screenshot?

Comment: related ?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8822/how-can-inner-parts-of-a-mesh-be-selected/8823#8823 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11038/what-is-the-difference-between-an-edge-loop-and-an-edge-ring/11039#11039

Comment: this might be useful: http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html?highlight=edge%20loop

Comment: In edit mode or object mode? In edit mode, you would press L while your mouse is hovering over part of the circle or you can select one vertex or edge and press Ctrl+L. If you're in object mode, you can usually zoom into the object and click to select. If it's still impossible, you can Alt+click the circle and select it from a list of objects that pops up.

Answer (score 4):

In edit mode Hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> and right click on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse over the circle and press "L".  This selects any mesh island that the mouse is hovering over.

Of course, this will only work if your circle isn't connected to anything.