# How to select polygons facing camera instead of polygons located in the opposite side

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I want to select marked face:

[image]

however back face gets selected:

[image]

Is there an option in blender to only select facing polygons camera ?

Comment: You should turn on *Limit Selection to visible* in the 3D View header.

Comment: This question is similar to [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8822/), and the answer to that question applies to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select 'Limit Selection to Visible' on the bar at the bottom of the window.

[image]

Comment: Correct - image updated.

Answer (score 6):

While in Edit mode and (by default) along the bottom of the 3D view, between the Vertex/Edge/Face selection and the Magnet will be an icon that looks like two square polygon faces with four vertices on the corners with one face being in front of the other.

Hovering over this button will bring a tooltip that says **"Limit selection to visible (clipped depthbuffer)"**. Toggling this button will change between the model being solid or transparent.  When the model appears solid, you will only select faces that are directly under the arrow, and not faces that might be behind it.

I wish I could post a screenshot but I'm unable to at the moment.